# Is there a way to create Geospatial PDF with OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers

I have a map and some layer and I want to export it in Geospatial PDF.
I'm able to export it to a PDF document with jspdf just like the ol example (https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/export-pdf.html)
but the output .pdf is not georeferencing.

Is there a way to produce a Geospatial PDF with OpenLayers?

Comment: its using the jspdf library and from documentation is does not support geospatial pdf exports http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/

Comment: Thanks @Mapperz. do you know another way with openlayers?